# How to correctly use Vue 3 composition-api across multiple Vue instances in multiple files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

**tl;dr** What is the correct way to import Vue3 in a base js file, then use Vue's composition-api in other standalone js files that will be loaded after that base file?

---

I am using Vue to enhance user experience in specific pages. For example, in register page to perform ajax requests and show server errors without page reloads. In short, mini SPAs within MPA...

In Vue2, importing Vue in the base file, then instantiating a new Vue instance and using Vue's options-api in subsequent files worked without problems. And the size of subsequent files were kept minimal since they contained only the logic needed for that file.

However, due to the fact that Vue3's composition-api requires importing `ref, reactive, watch, onMount...etc`, this results in the subsequent files importing Vue all over again. My attempt to overcome this is as follows:

```
// register.blade.php (contains)
<div id="root">
  <input type="text" name="first_name" v-model="FirstName">
  <input type="text" name="last_name" v-model="LastName">
// (before edit) <script src="main.js"></script>
// (before edit) <script src="register.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ mix('/main.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ mix('/register.js') }}"></script>
</div>
```

```
// main.js (contains)
// (before edit) import Vue from 'node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js';
// (before edit) window.Vue = Vue;
window.Vue = require('vue');
```

```
// register.js (contains)
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const FirstName = Vue.ref('');
    const LastName = Vue.ref('');
    const FullName = Vue.computed(() => FirstName.value + ' ' + LastName.value);

    return {
      FirstName, LastName, FullName
    }
  }
});
app.mount('#root');
```

This works fine for this trivial example, but I am wondering if the approach of prefixing with `Vue.` is even correct? Is it ok to access all the functions exposed by Vue for the setup() method using that approach ?

**EDIT:**
I am using *webpack* wrapped by *laravel mix*, I stripped that from the initial code for simplicity, but I think it proved relevant. Edits in the initially provided code are commented to avoid confusion.

```
// webpack.mix.js (contains)
mix.webpackConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js'),
    }
  }
});

mix.js('resources/main.js', 'public/main.js')
  .js('resources/register.js', 'public/register.js')
  .version();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no extra overhead when importing the separate parts from Vue 3 (`ref`, `watch`, `computed`…) in every one of your `.js` files. In fact, if you're using a bundler this will help the tree shaking process make the resulting files smaller ([great explanation by Evan You](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLpLYhnGqPA&t=2104)).

There's nothing wrong with importing all of Vue and using it the way you currently are, similar to how you would have in Vue 2. If the syntax bothers you, you could destructure what you use, i.e.

```js
// register.js (contains)
const { ref, computed } = Vue;

const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const FirstName = ref('');
    const LastName = ref('');
    const FullName = computed(() => FirstName.value + ' ' + LastName.value);

    return {
      FirstName, LastName, FullName
    }
  }
});

app.mount('#root');
```

**EDIT:**

I'm not familiar with Laravel Mix, but perhaps you could try something like this:

```js
// webpack.mix.js (contains)
const jsfiles = [
    'resources/main.js',
    'public/main.js',
    'resources/register.js',
    'public/register.js',
];

mix.js(...jsFiles).extract(['vue']).webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js'),
        }
    }
}).version();

// now in your `register.js` and `main.js` use `import`, not `require`
//
// import Vue from 'vue';
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly fine. I updated the code to better present how is the bundling handled. I am wondering if there is a better way to attempt the import in `main.js` to get proper tree shaking, since I guess right now Vue is imported as a whole. So if I am keeping track of all the functionality used by all the subsequent files that will come after `main.js`, is there a better way to import and still be able to use the syntax without prefixing ? Thanks again for `const { ref, computed } = Vue;`

Comment: I've updated my answer. I wonder if it's due to using `require` instead of `import`.

Comment: Extracting did generate `manifest.js` and `vendor.js`, where `vendor.js` size reflecting that Vue as a whole was imported. Then, when importing Vue using `import Vue from 'vue';` in any other file, it ends up importing Vue again in that file. Your first answer was already perfect for the original question, as for the follow-up question regarding tree shaking, maybe Laravel Mix itself needs modification to support proper tree shaking for Vue3. Thanks again for `const { ref, computed } = Vue;`

Comment: Update: current version of Laravel Mix 5 only supports Vue2, the [beta version](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/UPGRADE.md) of Laravel Mix 6 supports Vue3 and tree shaking worked fine. One bug to consider while extracting vendor files in `webpack.mix.js` is that using `mix.extract(['vue'])` resulted in duplicating vue in all files importing from vue, while using the wildcard `mix.extract()` to extract all used node_modules libraries, resulted in proper tree shaking and vue wasn't duplicated in any file importing from vue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Vue.ref` or `ref` if you desctructure like this `import {ref,reactive} from 'vue/dist/vue.js';`

This should not be necessary:

```
window.Vue = Vue;
```

as long as you use `import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';` in each file, like `register.js` (or the destructured version). Even when you have multiple imports, it doesn't mean that it will be re-included multiple times. The bundler will only add Vue (or parts of Vue library) once.

Comment: By adding `import { ref, computed } from 'vue';` in `register.js` and compiling with laravel mix, the file size jumps from a few kilobytes to 1.04 MiB. I assume this is because webpack doesn't know that `register.js` will come after `main.js` and will inherit what is already imported in `main.js`. Please accept my apology if my question before the edit didn't paint the full picture